# Which language has better support for developing GUIs coupled with network programming, Python or Java?

Tags: java, python, swing, user-interface

I am looking to develop an application as a personal project. What I have in mind is a network-based application that would entail writing code for a typical client-server architecture using TCP Sockets as well as a heavy use of GUIs. 
I believe I have quite a few choices: Swing in Java, PyQt, PyGTK, wxpython and the like in Python.
I was just wondering if anyone could direct me to which language would be better in the above respects.

Comment: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have updated the question now, maybe it's not so open-ended now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you go for `JavaFX`. It comes with the JDK and has a lot of good features.
Plus, it can inter-operate with Swing, backwards and forwards. It allows you to use CSS to pretty-paint your UI. t gives you best of both the worlds.